# List of OpenID Provider logo images and login URLs?

Tags: url, openid, graphical-logo

Is there a list of OpenID providers with their logos and OpenID URLs available anywhere, for use on a login page like the one here on Stack Exchange?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[OpenID-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) has a collection of images in their SVN repository:

http://openid-selector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/images/

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia has a list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openid), and you can probably gather the logos from there.